# AngularDart components and model binding

Tags: angularjs, dart, angular-dart

Is it possible to bind an AngularDart ngComponent to a model and then manipulate that model from the component and see the changes outside of the changes outside of ngComponent. For example

```
<myawsomecomponent ng-model="{{name}}"></myawesomecomponent>
<label>{{name}}</label>
```

myAwesomeComponent will do some kind of magic (for example capitalise all letters) to the model and that should be reflected outside of the component.

What's the best way to do something like this in AngularDart?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Great question!  To accomplish this task, you would inject the `NgModel` directive into `myAwesomeComponent`.  Then you'll be able to get and set the model through `NgModel.modelValue`.

```dart
@NgComponent(
  selector: 'myawesomecomponent',
  ...
)
class MyAwesomeComponent {
  NgModel _ngModel;
  MyAwesomeComponent(this._ngModel);

  ...
}
```

By adding an `ng-model` attribute to your element, Angular creates a `NgModel` directive.  The injection system will give you the `NgModel` for your particular element.

Take a look at how other NgModel directives are written, such as [InputCheckboxDirective](https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/blob/master/lib/directive/ng_model.dart#L74)

Comment: One other question, after looking at the code, I've seen modelValue and viewValue properties in NgModel. What is the difference? Also I've seen for inputCheckbox that scope.$apply is called onInputChange. What is the reason for that? In other words, when do I need to call scope.$apply? Thanks.

Comment: modelValue and viewValue will be different once converters are implemented  (e.g. viewValue may be "4388 1200 6000 5344" where the modelValue may be "4388120060005344")      The reference to scope.$apply is cruft; it has no value and should be removed. (PRs welcome!)